# I am unable to fetch data to html page from database in django

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I am trying to fetch data to html page from database but i am not getting any output on the html page

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class image(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='slideshow1')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import image
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(image)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import image
def slideshow1(request):
    dest=image.objects.all()
    return render(request,'slideshow1.html',{'dest':dest})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',views.login,name='login'),
    path('signup/',views.signupform,name='signup'),
    path('logout/',views.logout,name='logout'),
    path('slideshow1',views.slideshow1,name='slideshow1'),
]
```

slideshow1.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<h1 >{{image.name}}</h1>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not access all the data without using 'for loop' even you have only one entry in the table. So use loop to extract it.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for x in image %}
<h1 >{{x.name}}</h1>
<img src="{{x.img.url}}">
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```